# Error in updating the value of 'url' tags in a xml file

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<server>

    <url>http://chskab.budsbksa.com</url>

    <url>https://chskab.budsbksa.com</url>

</server>
```

So I want all the value in the tag `url` to be changed to 
`<url>url</url>`

```
$path = "C:\Users\1026256\Desktop"
$path = "C:\Users\1026256\Desktop"
$input = $path + "\Hellogit.xml"
$output = $path + "\Hellogit_updated.xml"

Copy-item $input $output

[xml]$XmlDocument = get-content -Path $output
$root = [xml]$XmlDocument

$i = "url"
$root.server.url[1] = $i

$root.server.url
$root.Save($output)
```

Expected Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<server>

    <url>url</url>

    <url>url</url>

</server>
```

Any suggestions on how I can improve my code?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path $input
$XmlDocument | % { $_.server.SelectNodes("url") | % { $_.InnerText = "url"  }  }
$XmlDocument.Save($output)
```

Comment: Only a small change in your code, get node as XmlElement: $root.server.SelectNodes("url")[0].InnerText = $i